# Getting count of each item

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
Select count(*) as TotalCount from ABC where ID in (1,3,6)
```

The problem here is that it gives me the total count of 1,3 and 6. But I would like to get the count for each  ID, something like shown below:

```
TotalCount, ID
6,          1
2,          3
5,          6
```

Kindly let me know the SQL Server query for achieving this. I wouldn't prefer to use Temp tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply add the id to the selected columns and group by them:

```
Select id, count(*) as TotalCount from ABC where ID in (1,3,6)
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot krock. One more thing. If I need to pass 1,3,6 as parameter for a stored procedure, how will I do it?

Comment: This is more difficult to answer, on a quick search across other so questions always refers to this site [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*),id from abc where id in (1,3,6) group by id;
```