# Group by column and display count from all tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Table1 looks like this:

```
id   type    
1    bike     
2    car      
3    cycle
4    bike
```

And Table2 looks like this:

```
id   type    
1    bike     
2    car
```

I want my final output to look like the following:

```
type   count_table1   count_table2
bike        2            1
car         1            1 
cycle       1            0
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Actually the most efficient way to do this in mysql would be another schema design, i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution, no need for complicated table joins & functions:

```
SELECT type, MAX(count_table1) as count_table1, MAX(count_table2) as count_table2 FROM (
(
    SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS count_table1, 0 AS count_table2
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY type
) UNION (
    SELECT type, 0 AS count_table1, COUNT(*) AS count_table2
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY type)
) AS tmp
GROUP BY type
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad44e/4/0)

Comment: Good (and simple) answer!

Comment: Great answer. It is works for me . And also i want to add one more table (i.e) table 3 and i need count for that table also..

Comment: Maybe you should consider changing schema design as STT LCU suggested. Anyways, here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e72ff/1/0) with 3 tables

Comment: Also have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb4cd0/1/0) with just one table. Isn't this what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT t1.TYPE, 
       ifnull(t1.COUNT1,0) CountTable1, 
       ifnull(t2.COUNT2,0) CountTable2 
FROM   (SELECT TYPE, 
               COUNT(*) count1 
        FROM   TABLE1 
        GROUP  BY TYPE)T1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT TYPE, 
                         COUNT(*) count2 
                  FROM   TABLE2 
                  GROUP  BY TYPE)T2 
              ON t1.TYPE = t2.TYPE 
UNION 
SELECT t1.TYPE, 
       t1.COUNT1, 
       t2.COUNT2 
FROM   (SELECT TYPE, 
               COUNT(*) count1 
        FROM   TABLE1 
        GROUP  BY TYPE)T1 
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT TYPE, 
                          COUNT(*) count2 
                   FROM   TABLE2 
                   GROUP  BY TYPE)T2 
               ON t1.TYPE = t2.TYPE
```

See my working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea/14).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.TYPE, 
       COUNT(a.ID), 
       COUNT(b.ID) 
FROM   TABLE1 AS a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 AS b 
                    ON a.TYPE = b.TYPE 
GROUP  BY a.TYPE 
UNION 
SELECT b.TYPE, 
       COUNT(a.ID), 
       COUNT(b.ID) 
FROM   TABLE1 AS a 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 AS b 
                     ON a.TYPE = b.TYPE 
GROUP  BY b.TYPE
```

Comment: When I run your query, I get different results from what I expect. Can you check why this is happening? I used the data set I made in SQL Fiddle with your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea/23

Comment: @Gidil. I should have used count(distinct id), thank for pointing it out. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea/36

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it

```
SELECT a.type, 
       COALESCE(b.type_count, 0) count_table1,
       COALESCE(c.type_count, 0) count_table2
  FROM
(
  SELECT type FROM Table1
  UNION 
  SELECT type FROM Table2
) a LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT type, COUNT(*) type_count
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY type
) b ON a.type = b.type LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT type, COUNT(*) type_count
    FROM Table2
   GROUP BY type
) c ON a.type = c.type
```

Some explanation:

- Subquery `a` gets a distinct list of types (`UNION` takes care of that).
- Subquery `b` and `c` calculate number of type occurrences in `table1` and `table2` respectively.
- And finally an outer `SELECT` brings it all together using `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to substitute non existent values with `0`.

Output:

```
|  TYPE | COUNT_TABLE1 | COUNT_TABLE2 |
|-------|--------------|--------------|
|  bike |            2 |            1 |
|   car |            1 |            1 |
| cycle |            1 |            0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea/21)** demo

Answer (score 1):

```
select type, count(*) from table1 group by type

select type, count(*) from table2 group by type
```

[Getting count of each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216761/getting-count-of-each-item)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.`TYPE`, 
       COALESCE(tbl1CNT,0) as tbl1CNT,
       COALESCE(tbl2CNT,0) as tbl2CNT
FROM   (SELECT `TYPE` 
        FROM   TABLE1 
        UNION 
        SELECT `TYPE` 
        FROM   TABLE2) a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `TYPE`, 
                         COUNT(*) AS tbl1CNT 
                  FROM   TABLE1 
                  GROUP  BY `TYPE`) b 
              ON a.`TYPE` = b. `TYPE` 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `TYPE`, 
                         COUNT(*) AS tbl2CNT 
                  FROM   TABLE2 
                  GROUP  BY `TYPE`) c 
              ON a.`TYPE` = c. `TYPE`
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc9ea/33)**

Comment: Note that this query returns a NULL where a 0 is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    T.type
    ,IFNULL(COUNT(T1.type),0) as 'count_table1'
    ,IFNULL(COUNT(T2.type),0) as 'count_table2'
from
    Table1 as T1
    left join Table2 as T2 on T2.id = T1.id
group by
    T.type

union

select
    T.type
    ,IFNULL(COUNT(T1.type),0) as 'count_table1'
    ,IFNULL(COUNT(T2.type),0) as 'count_table2'
from
    Table2 as T
    left join Table1 as T1 on T1.id = T2.id
group by
    T.type
```

Comment: Please note that this question is in MYSQL, so ISNULL doesn't work.